# How to store TSQL query results for later display

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, odata

I've never used TSQL before, but I decided I wanted to poke around in the SO [data dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/) anyways. So this is probably a rookie question. I did try to search for an answer, but I don't know the technical term for what I'm trying to do, and search is only so good if you don't have the right keywords.

My goal is to find out how many questions have a score of 0, how many have a score of 1, how many have a score of 2, &c. I can write a query to find out those individual counts, no problem. I'd like to be able to run a query containing a loop, though. Here's what I'm using so far:

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
WHILE @counter < 3
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        Posts
    WHERE
        PostTypeId = 1
    AND
        Score = @counter

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

(**EDIT**: the eventual goal is to expand from [0, 3] to [-100, 1000] or whatever is necessary to hit all existing questions) Obviously, my problem is that I'm grabbing the count in each cycle of the loop and then not doing anything with it. Currently, the result I get is just the count of whatever `@counter` is set to initially; the number of iterations is irrelevant. Is it possible to store the results somewhere and then display as something like:

```
+-------+--------------------------------+
| Score | NumberOfQuestionsWithThatScore |
+-------+--------------------------------+
|   -10 |                           111  |
+-------+--------------------------------+
|    -9 |                             0  |
+-------+--------------------------------+
|    -8 |                           248  |
+-------+--------------------------------+
|   ... |                           ...  |
+-------+--------------------------------+
```

(**EDIT**: any reasonably clear display is fine, the above table is just a sample; **EDIT 2**: modified the design of the table to clear up continuing confusion)

If so, what is this called, and how is it done?

Comment: since you are new to TSQL, I'll offer you this advice: **if you start to write a loop, you're probably doing something wrong!**  Your loop can be written as a single query, which will run several factors faster than your loop.

Comment: @theUserWhoDeletedHisAnswer: FWIW, I almost downvoted it, but then I added `ORDER BY Score ASC` and it worked pretty well for my immediate goal, so I would have upvoted (the only thing it was missing was zero-score entries). Though I'm still curious whether storing results from a loop is possible, for future reference.

Comment: @Lord - That was me. I deleted it as it was similar to GrayWizardx and 2 minutes later. Yes. You can use table variables or temporary tables to store transient materialised results.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, you can declare local variables to store values in, a table variable might help you: `DECALRE @Scores table (Score int, CountOf int)`, then in the loop insert into this table once per iteration.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, do you actually need the results to display across the page, or would it be acceptable to return them down the page? (The latter is a lot easier in SQL.)

Comment: @Mark, nope, I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Martin, ah, okay, I just happened to try yours first, perhaps because it looked the most similar to my starter code and I subconsciously decided I could understand it best.

Comment: @KM, interesting, I didn't think that would be legal, but SEDE didn't balk at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can do this in a single pass...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 And Score <= 3
Group By Score
```

That should give you a nice table like:

```
Score   Total
0       2490
1       2904
2       2110
```

Sore thats off the cuff, not in front of a DB right now to verify the syntax. Look up "Group By" to get a better idea.

AS @OMG Ponies points out this is not pivot'ed as you originally had. If you want to have a single column, you would need to use SELECT and SUM to do that.

Comment: The `MAX(Score)` isn't needed as that's the `group by` field.

Comment: For this question you can run queries interactively here by the way http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @OMG I forgot to ammend my own post about that. I havent done PIVOT in TSQL (Azure or otherwise). Good point.Your Answer is closer to the desired output. I +1'ed your answer

Answer (score 6):

The output you listed is a standard pivot query, turning rows into columnar data:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.score = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ScoreOfZero,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ScoreOfOne,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.score = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ScoreOfTwo
  FROM POSTS p
```

Comment: This does appear to work (for all posts), but isn't easily expandable to cover all cases from `ScoreOfNegativeFifty` to `ScoreOfThreeThousand`. +1 for enlightening me about `SUM` and `CASE`, though.

Comment: (Also, thanks for being so scrupulous about the display format; I didn't intend for it to be followed so exactly, but another virtual +1 to you for it. I've edited to reflect this.)

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: That requires [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:  This is just a fleshed out solution based on the original methodology, but provides a row for every Score count from the minimum to the maximum, including zero count scores.

```
--Posts per score, with zeros.

declare @minScore int
declare @maxScore int
declare @current int
declare @postType int

set @postType = 1

set @minScore = (select MIN(Score) from Posts where PostTypeId = @postType)
set @maxScore = (select MAX(Score) from Posts where PostTypeId = @postType)

set @current = @minScore

create table #myTemp (Score int, PostsCount int) 

insert into #myTemp
select Score, count(*) from Posts group by Score

while @current < @maxScore
begin
  insert into #myTemp
  select @current, 0
    where not exists (select 1 from #myTemp where Score = @current and PostTypeId = @postType)
  set @current = @current + 1
end

select * from #myTemp order by Score
​
```

Example 2: A cheesy dynamic SQL approach with the Columns as the scores, each column being a sub-query.  Disclaimer: SEDE seems to execute it all, but you do not get the results.  If you instead `select @dynSQL` at the end and then run that, you'll get the data.

```
-- Dynamic SQL count of all posts for a score

declare @minScore int
declare @maxScore int
declare @current int
declare @postType int
declare @dynSQL nvarchar(MAX)

set @postType = 1

set @minScore = (select MIN(Score) from Posts where PostTypeId = @postType)
set @maxScore = (select MAX(Score) from Posts where PostTypeId = @postType)

set @current = @minScore

set @dynSQL = 'select '

while @current <= @maxScore
begin
    set @dynSQL = @dynSQL 
                  + '(select count(*) from Posts where PostTypeId = ' 
                  + convert(varchar,@postType) + ' and Score = ' 
                  + convert(varchar,@current) + ') as Score_'
                  + CASE WHEN @current < 0 THEN 'Negative_' 
                              + convert(varchar,ABS(@current)) 
                         ELSE convert(varchar,@current)
                         END
    if @current < @maxScore set @dynSQL = @dynSQL + ', '
    set @current = @current + 1
end

exec(@dynSQL)
​
```